# How to tell vim to NOT REREAD FILE when I switch back to it

Tags: vim

My list of actions:

```
e xx.txt
e xx2.txt
"in a different window change xx.txt
:b#
```

At this point I would like vim to tell me that the buffer has changed, but to not load new contents into the buffer.
Note: I do not have autoread set.

Below is a list of my options.

```
:set
--- Options ---
  expandtab           ignorecase          scroll=13           tabstop=4
  filetype=text       laststatus=3        shiftwidth=4        title
  helplang=en       nomodeline            smartcase           ttyfast
  history=50          ruler               syntax=text         ttymouse=xterm2
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  fileencoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  printoptions=paper:letter
  runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/
vim73,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
  suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg
,.inx,.out,.toc
  tags=../tags,./tags,tags;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set global parameter in your `.vimrc`

```
set hidden
```

or specify `hidden` attribute for selected buffer using `bufhidden`.
When the buffer is `hidden` (not abandoned like default) when you modify it outside vim you will be noticed that some changes occured and you can load new content or discard this changes.

Comment: That did it. Thank you. Not exactly straight forward or obvious, but sometimes that is VIM.